# Need to separate month and year input box while using stripe V7.2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I am using [ngx-stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe) Version 7.2.0 for UI in angular. Is there any way to separate Month and year and create two different text boxes in UI in angular 7 instead of one field?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can be done as Stripe controls the UI used to collect the card details. This is part of their [Elements](https://stripe.com/payments/elements) product which helps you meet PCI compliance requirements easily and you can not split the expiration date in two fields.